# Draw a function from 2D to 1D as an heat map: Matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a function `w` from 2D coordinate space to 1D values, such that

```
w(a,b) := min(a,b)
```

I want to represent this function as an heat map in Matlab.

For example, I draw a square on the Cartesian plane with vertices `(0,0)`, `(0,1)`, `(1,0)`, `(0,0)`. Then I colour the region inside the square, by assigning the same colour to any two pairs of points `(a,b)` and `(c,d)` if `w(a,b)=w(c,d)`.

Is my understanding of a heatmap correct? If so, how can I achieve this in Matlab?

Comment: hummmm `[0,1]^2` is `[0,1]`......

Comment: As well as surf and contourf there is [`pcolor`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) (closer to surf).

Comment: Thanks @Steve, that might be a good option as it's a direct 2D plot, I didn't know that function existed! I've included alternative links at the end of my answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with `surf`, which plots a surface which looks like a heatmap when viewed from above. See the commented code for details:

```
% Define axes points as [0,0.1,0.2,...,1]
ax = 0:0.1:1;  
% Make grid of values corresponding to min(x,y)
xy = bsxfun(@min, ax, ax');
% Plot
surf(xy); % Plot surface
view(2);  % Look from "above" onto x-y plane
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', ax) % Set x-axis labels
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', ax) % Set y-axis labels
colorbar; % Show colorbar as a legend
```

Output:

[image: heatmap]

You can extend this by using a custom function if `min` was just an example.

```
ax = 0:0.1:1;  
% Define function
w = @(a,b) a - exp(b)
% Use custom function inside bsxfun
xy = bsxfun(w, ax, ax');
surf(xy); % ... etc
```

See the docs for details: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html

---

Also see the docs for [`pcolor`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) which creates a 2D colour plot so no perspective change is needed, and [`contourf`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html) which outlines regions not all squares.